# Calling a javascript function on a button click

Tags: javascript, html, function

Note: I have properly closed my div tags, the code was too long, hence posted the main snippet.

I tried with the onclick event but the table isn't showing up hence I changed my code back to original

```
<body>




<button onclick="fetchAndDisplayData()">Click me</button>
                      <table id="id01" class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
                        <tbody>
                        <thead>

                          <tr>
                            <th>Title </th>

                            </tr>
                    </thead>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
<script>
  function fetchAndDisplayData() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8888/api/get/read1.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }

};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
  function myFunction(arr) {
      var out = "";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          out += '<tr><td><a href="' + arr[i].link + '">' +
              arr[i].title + '</a></td>';
          out += '<td>' + arr[i].description + '<br></td>';
          out += '<td>' + arr[i].log_time + '<br></td>';
          out += '<td><a href="' + arr[i].link + '">' +
              arr[i].link + '</a></td></tr>';
      }

      document.getElementById("#id01 tbody").innerHTML = out;

}
}
  </script>

</body>
```

I want a button such that only when I click on the button, then I get those entries. What changes can I make? Please help me with the code. It's for a project.

Comment: You're assigning HTML code in variable `out` to event handler `onclick`? Did you mean `innerHTML` instead of `onclick`?

Comment: no, please check the updated code. There is a button called click me. I want to display the table values like description and log time only when the button is clicked @alx

Comment: You need to wrap whole code -- from `var xmlhttp...` to the end of the script -- into new function, and then call it in `onclick` event handler of that button. Still, the other part is invalid -- you can't assign HTML to `.onclick` event handler, that does not make sense.

Comment: It's not displaying any data and I am getting this error: @alx

test.html:104 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at myFunction (test.html:104)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (test.html:84)

Answer (score 0):

Your script must be modified like this:

```js
<script>
var show = true;

function fetchAndDisplayData() {
    if (show) {
        show = false
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://localhost:8888/api/get/read1.php";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                myFunction(myArr);
            }

        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } else {
        show = true;
        myFunction([]);
    }
}

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<tr><td><a href="' + arr[i].link + '">' +
            arr[i].title + '</a></td>';
        out += '<td>' + arr[i].description + '<br></td>';
        out += '<td>' + arr[i].log_time + '<br></td>';
        out += '<td><a href="' + arr[i].link + '">' +
            arr[i].link + '</a></td></tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML = out;
}

fetchAndDisplayData();
</script>
```

And your button should have this handler code instead:

```html
<button onclick="fetchAndDisplayData()">Click me</button>
```

But there are other errors in your code (see my comment above), and I guess these changes won't make it work right away.

Comment: Hi, it's still not displaying the data. Error:
test.html:104 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at myFunction (test.html:104)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (test.html:84)

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, and you removed `#` before `id01` in selector... That's why you see that error.

Comment: Next thing you'll probably want to replace `.onclick` with `.innerHTML`. Just saving you a round-trip here.

Comment: still the same. Can you recheck again, here I believe there is a silly mistake somewhere. I am doing as you mentioned and I have updated this time my full code. Error screenshot: http://prntscr.com/o5extt

Comment: Can you post your full code into the qustion again, please? Or in jsfiddle, or something. I can't see how `out is not defined` occurs in `fetchAndDisplayData()`. I'd rather see full code instead of guessing.

Comment: There are alot of files @alx

Comment: normally my data would display but not with the button

Comment: I have posted the file again, please check

Comment: Wasn't talking about *all* files, only about this HTML+JS file (or snippet). Your corrected version looks good, with exception of `<thead>` inside of `<tbody>` -- I'd rather move it outside. Any error messages? Also, if you want it to update table on load, just add `fetchAndDisplayData();` right before closing `</script>` tag (I'll update my answer).

Comment: I did the new changes too, this is the error message: @alx
test1.html:108 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at myFunction (test1.html:108)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: I know what's wrong, give me a sec, I'll update my answer.

Comment: See updated code (only line with `innerHTML` has changed). Selector was jQuery-like -- i.e. complex expression, but `getElementById` works only with IDs (btw my apologies, I had to remove `#` again, brainfarted heavily). So, either the construct I've added to my answer, or `document.querySelector('#id01 tbody').innerHTML` (TBH this one looks better).

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working great. Could you help me with one last bit please. Could you help me toggle that button. Like enabling and disabling. So when I click on that it shows the table but when I click back, it closes the table back again (enabling and disabling)

Comment: Updated the code, but that's a blind change as I can't run it in your environment, and there could be mistakes.

Comment: Oh, well but it was perfect. I need to get this toggled. I am troubled with this since a day, any chance that I can get the toggling enable and disable possible? @alx

Comment: My submission is tomorrow

Comment: I have updated the code, does it work? Any error messages?

Comment: No error messages. It's working great. Thank you very much.. Really. @alx. really! :)